# Moment of a function of Gaussian random variables: $\mathbb{E}[(a_{i}^{\top}AA^{\top}a_{j})^{q}]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, random-matrices

Let $A$ be an $m\times k$ matrix with iid $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ entries and $a_{i}$ and $a_{j}$ be its 
$i$th and $j$th columns. I would like to compute the following quantity:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[(a_{i}^{\top}AA^{\top}a_{j})^{q}],
\end{equation}
for $q\in\mathbb{N}$.

One can expand $a_{i}^{\top}AA^{\top}a_{j}$ to get
\begin{equation}
\|a_{i}\|_{2}^{2}a_{i}^{\top}a_{j}+\|a_{j}\|_{2}^{2}a_{i}^{\top}a_{j}+\sum_{t\in[k]\backslash\{i\}\cup\{j\}}(a_{i}^{\top}a_{t})(a_{j}^{\top}a_{t})
\end{equation}
 and explicitly compute the expectation for $q=1, 2$ etc. But how can I generalize for larger $q$?

Is there a general result on this? Any hints/references appreciated.

Comment: No sure how much it'd help, but "gaussian chaos" may be relevant. Maybe [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.2139)?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I had looked at this paper. The difficulty is that the terms $g_{n_{1}}\cdots g_{n_{d}}$ in the polynomial are independent gaussians, which may not be true for the expression I have